# Can you delete Firebase DNS TXT records after domain is verified?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it safe to remove the TXT records after your Firebase domain is verified?

Comment: Should be fine, but if you make any changes in the future to your config (e.g. changing your custom domain from site.com to foo.site.com), then they will need to be validated again. Is there some compelling reason to remove them?

Comment: No particular reason other than cleaning up the DNS records - after some time there's a lot of TXT records accumulating

Answer (score 12):

I removed my firebase hosting TXT records, and after about a month or so had passed, I received an email from Firebase asking me to re-verify the domain or it will be removed. So you do need to leave them there.